# JQuery custom event not firing/caught

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm loading some scripts dynamically as follows:

```
//fileA.js
$('body').on('LoginWidget', function() {
    $.cachedScript('/js/min/AddressWidgets.min.js').done(function() {
        extend(AddressBookWidget, ShippingAddressWidget);
        console.log("throwing event")
        $('body').trigger('ShippingAddressWidget loaded');
    });
});
```

and then:

```
//fileB.js
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            console.log("catching event")
            $('body').on('ShippingAddressWidget loaded', function() {
                // do stuff
            });
...
```

In the console, I see:

```
catching event
throwing event
```

But the event catcher is not triggered. jquery 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event names can not contain spaces.

You have to either use an event name like

```
$('body').on('ShippingAddressWidgetLoaded', function() {...
```

or namespace the event

```
$('body').on('ShippingAddressWidget.loaded', function() {...
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/e2t2tyvx/)

Comment: You are correct, and a great jsFiddle example, too.  I could not find the event name valid character set documented anywhere, however.